# How to trigger a ticket status change in Jira on a Bitbucket Pull request approve

Tags: bitbucket, jira, bitbucket-cloud

we have a workflow process that requires a jira ticket to automatically change status when code associated with it has a pull request approved.

For merging, creating, declining and reopening, this would just be a simple matter of adding a trigger to the appropriate transition in the jira workflow, but for some unexplained reason, PR approvals are not in the list of available triggers.

I can create a Bitbucket webhook that calls out to a test webhook listener when a PR approve event is triggered, but I have no idea how to make jira listen to that event, or then get it to transition the ticket's status appropriately.

We're using cloud versions of both bitbucket and jira.

All help gratefully received.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are right, there is no trigger for PR approvals.
Your approach is probably the only option until a trigger becomes available.
Here´s a presentation that explains how to do it, but  I am afraid it requires Server to implement:

https://youtu.be/CDzUaflgcRw

Comment: Sadly we're not on Server, so this won't work for us.